# Curso intensivo de python de Eric Matthes ex8.10

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com dificuldade para fazer um exercício do livro 'Curso intensivo de python de Eric Matthes' o exercícios é o seguinte:

8.10 - Grandes magicos: Comesse com uma copia de seu programa do exercício 8.9. Escreva uma função chamada make_great() que modifique a lista de mágicos acrescentando a Expressão 'O Grande' ao nome de cada magico. Chame show_magicians() para ver se a lista foi realmente alterada.

Eu fiz o exercício 8.9 e ficou da seguinte forma:

```
def show_magiciasns():

   lista=['Howard Thurston', 'David Copperfield', "Lance Burton", 'Houdini',
   'David Blaine', 'Dynamo', 'Derren Brown', 'Criss Angel']

   for magicos in lista:
      print (magicos)

show_magiciasns()
```

A minha duvida é em criar uma função que altere essa lista.

Comment: Já resolveu o exercício 8.9? Espero que sim, então edite e coloque o código. Aproveite e descreva qual foi sua dificuldade ao resolver este exercício.

Comment: Victor, existe o botão [edit] para adicionar informações na pergunta. Além disso, será interessante você fazer o [tour] e ler o guia de [ask]. Outras informações você pode achar na [help].

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar uma [`compreensão de lista`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compreens%C3%A3o_de_lista) para concatenar a string `O grande` na frente de cada elemento/string da lista de mágicos, veja só:

```
lista=['Howard Thurston', 'David Copperfield', "Lance Burton", 'Houdini',
       'David Blaine', 'Dynamo', 'Derren Brown', 'Criss Angel']

print([ 'O grande ' + magico for magico in lista ])
```

Colocando tudo junto:

```
def make_great( lista ):
    return [ 'O grande ' + magico for magico in lista ]

def show_magicians( lista ):
   for magico in lista:
      print(magico)

lista=['Howard Thurston', 'David Copperfield', "Lance Burton", 'Houdini',
   'David Blaine', 'Dynamo', 'Derren Brown', 'Criss Angel']

show_magicians( make_great(lista) )
```

Saída:

```
O grande Howard Thurston
O grande David Copperfield
O grande Lance Burton
O grande Houdini
O grande David Blaine
O grande Dynamo
O grande Derren Brown
O grande Criss Angel
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/5pmcKB)

Comment: cara eu testei aqui e ta tudo certo valeu, vou estudar mais esse código porque essa parte de funções com listas ta fritando a o meu cérebro.

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço o livro mas pelo que entendi o exercício te manda criar uma nova função e não modificar a já existente, assim você precisará criar esta segunda função, a `make_great()` para para devolver o nome do mágico com a sequência "O grande " nele:

```
def make_great(magician):
    return "O grande " + magician
```

Você a chamará dentro de `show_magicians()`, colocando-a antes de imprimir o nome do mágico:

```
def show_magicians():
    # ...
        print(make_great(magicos))
    # ...
```

Deste modo, a cada passagem do laço, a função `make_great()` é chamada com o nome do mágico que acrescentará o prefixo "O Grande " e devolver o resultado para o comando `print()`.